# How to make Slider functional on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android

I got a problem Slider (Seekbar) doesn't working for me on Android. I got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tutorme, PID: 16570
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorme/com.example.tutorme.activities.FilterTutorActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.tutorme:layout/activity_filter_tutor: Binary XML file line #60 in com.example.tutorme:layout/content_filter_tutor: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.tutorme:layout/activity_filter_tutor: Binary XML file line #60 in com.example.tutorme:layout/content_filter_tutor: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60 in com.example.tutorme:layout/content_filter_tutor: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.arch.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.slider.Slider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tutorme--82CKvkCUOgphFA8Gwf4Hw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tutorme--82CKvkCUOgphFA8Gwf4Hw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 35 more
```

And this is how my styles look like:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimarySurface">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/white</item>
        <item name="switchStyle">@style/Widget.App.Switch</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.App.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

    <style name="dialog_image_option_container">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/basic_indentation</item>
    </style>
    <style name="dialog_image_option_image">
        <item name="android:layout_width">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="dialog_image_option_text">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/basic_indentation</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Switch" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Switch</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Switch" parent="">
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I got dependency. I migrated to AndroidX. I am using AppCompatActivity(), etc. **BUT...**
I am not able to find solution on Internet, so I'm asking you for first time guys to help me. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Here is layout:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.AddEditTutorActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_filter_tutor">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:hint="@string/subject"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_subject_color_primary_dark_24dp"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/first_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:hint="@string/place"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_place_color_secondary_dark_24dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/place"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:valueFrom="0.0"
            android:valueTo="100.0"
            android:stepSize="10.0" />


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/stars_layout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:helperTextEnabled="true"
                app:helperText="@string/range"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:hint="@string/rating"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_star_color_secondary_dark_24dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/stars"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_computer_color_secondary_dark_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/basic_indentation"
                    android:text="@string/online_class"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:id="@+id/onlineLecture"
                    style="@style/Widget.App.Switch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/double_indentation"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_group_color_secondary_dark_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/basic_indentation"
                    android:text="@string/group_class"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:id="@+id/groupLecture"
                    style="@style/Widget.App.Switch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/double_indentation"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_indentation"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_indentation"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_home_color_dark_secondary_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/basic_indentation"
                    android:text="@string/home_class"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:id="@+id/homeLecture"
                    style="@style/Widget.App.Switch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/double_indentation"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/saveChanges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/save"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```
````

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and your layout.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti here it is.

Comment: Which version of material components are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ... 1.1.0 (implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0')

Comment: The Slider requires the version 1.2.0. Currently 1.2.0-beta01. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970043/implementation-of-google-design-guidelines-for-sliders/58499303#58499303

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti .. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="100"
    android:stepSize="10"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.PrimaryPalette.Red"/>
```

in values/styles.xml :-

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.PrimaryPalette.Red" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#e53935</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ab000d</item>
  </style>
```

material design library:

```
implementation  'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

Comment: you need the latest android material design library
``` implementation  'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'

Comment: The `android:theme` worked for me, thanks!